# Example of "technology trade"

Tags: website-design, conceptualization

I am trying to design a web template for my client. I designed a simple template too. but i got the following response from my client.

> We need to do a lot of modification
>   though the color scheme is okay.  The
>   theme should be "Technology trade" 
>   and which should represent IT,
>   Research Lab Equipments and Sanitation
>   and Sewerage Equipments. I suggest for
>   a fusion art of all these three
>   categories in one  shot if possible.

Here i don't understand what does technology trade actually refers too..

can i get some reference or idea of technology trade

Comment: I think "technology trade" is just a made-up term.

Comment: contrary to the other poster's comments, the client has provided you with the actual description of their business: google "LABORATORY EQUIPMENT FOR WATER AND SEWERAGE UTILITIES" and you will immediately find hits for other companies in this field. You might look to their logos and web designs for some idea of the industry's design sensibilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The client actually gave you a decent direction to start, despite the vague wording. You have three categories for photo research, and the emphasis is on "equipment."

So find a hundred images of machinery and people working on machines which look advanced, complicated, and professional — that is, nothing Mike Rowe would be doing on *Dirty Jobs* — and you can argue fits into IT, Lab Research, or Sanitation. The Sanitation one is obviously the most difficult, but you're kind of aiming for [this sort of image](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-9630906-hand-with-glove-is-cleaning-hospita-equipment.php).

Put together your hundred images and ask the client to pick the ones they like. That will help you refine the theme.

Comment: hm... so it may be good for me collecting machinery pics and talking with client again...

Comment: @KoolKabin: Yes, that's exactly what I would do. It will likely be much easier for the client to point to photos and say "this one, that one, not that one." Even if the client hates everything you pick, you can get a better sense of what the client *doesn't* want from that.

Comment: +1. Personally, I would have said "Find another client."  This answer is much better.

Comment: @Matthew: Let me know how that works out for you in a recession. :)

Comment: thnx guys for suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it means nothing. Your client is saying that he wants to looks like the site belongs to a company that is in the technology industry, but that really doesn't say anything in and of itself.

You're going to have to work with your client to get more details out of their true wants/requests. Ask questions that will help narrow down the visual direction he'd like you to go in. 'Technology Trade' is simply to vague to be of any real help.

"I suggest for a fusion art of all these three categories in one shot if possible."

As nice as that sounds, it's ridiculous. Is he asking for a photo of guy wearing a labcode playing on his iPhone while in a garbage can?

Comment: My first thought was "toilet connected to the internet".

Comment: ooh! I like that one! ;)

Comment: Click to jiggle the handle. Unless you buy the apple version, which never needs to be flushed but costs 3x as much as the Windows version.